# Why are using 'Yoga' tag if only want physical fitness?

Tags: feature-request

Yoga word is generated from `sanskrit` language word **`'yuj'`**. It means combining the things. i.e. mind+body+spirit.

If anyone don't accept mind or spirit involvement in yoga. They only want physical fitness (i.e. body) then why are they using 'Yoga' word. They should remove yoga word from tags. It is totally misuse of real meaning/concept of 'Yoga'.

How can one change the definition of yoga according to their own convenience. It is surprising. No matter you hold or close that question. But the truth is truth. I know it is physical fitness site. But denying real concept/definition is not also good practice. Instead you can change the tag 'yoga' to something other.

If you only want physical fitness then other many tags are there. Or even they can use only 'power yoga' tag or 'Yoga without spirituality' tag.

Real mining of yoga is union of mind, body and spirit. `[Definition is referred from "Certification of Yoga professionals Official Guidebook" (this is authorized yoga certification book)]`.

Comment: Words literally change their meaning with usage and time. While I'd (marginally) agree that using the word "yoga" is a bit of cultural appropriation, I don't see its current usage, encompassing both (what you call) "true" yoga, and what people interested only in the physical side of yoga, going away any time soon, so I don't believe re-tagging is helpful. I *do* think that for questions regarding a specific *style* of yoga should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a misuse of the word. This site is specifically about the *physical* aspect of fitness, and yoga includes a physical aspect, so it's included.

If you have questions about the physical performance of yoga, that's fine. But one of your questions was closed because it is about the philosophy and spiritual aspects of yoga, which isn't on-topic for this particular site.

Comment: Yoga tag covers all 3 parts i.e. body+mind+spirit. Yoga can not be separated by only physical aspect of fitness. If anyone tries to separate yoga by only 'body' then it is not yoga. It is something else. 'Yoga' word itself contains meaning i.e. 'Combination'. Combination of these 3 parts. Breaking of them would be breaking of yoga.

Comment: We could add a tag called "the-physical-part-of-yoga" but that's a bit more unwieldy. The tag is yoga, and it exists on a **Physical** Exercise forum. The limitation should be clear from this.

Comment: If you people want to change 'yoga' tag then 'Power yoga' is better. But, if you don't want to change 'yoga' tag then such questions will arise. And closing or holding them would be unncessarily denying the truth. Now, I understand your requirements but taking support of 'yoga' tag will give you these type of questions which includes not only body but also mind+spirit.

Comment: No, I see no reason to replace the tag. Power yoga is a branch of yoga, and cannot replace the scope of this tag. Yoga, refers to yoga as a whole, but questions about the spiritual aspects of it will be referred elsewhere. It doesn't need to be more complicated than that. Some people ask about how to perform the physical side of yoga, and that's why we have the tag. People who ask about the spiritual side will be referred to the Help Center which describes the scope of the site. No further action required.

Comment: ok, breaking of 'yoga'

Comment: It's a separation of a topic with many aspects. Computer science is a big topic, but there are different sites for coding, database administration, devops, career advice, etc. It's nothing new or unusual to separate a topic into its smaller parts.

Comment: Regarding 'computer science' context, Let us think that from 'computer science' -- if you are removing 'computer' then nothing remains. No coding, No db administration, No developments, No ..... etc. Computer is main 'soul' of all this. Similarly, mind is soul of yoga... :-)

Comment: That's like saying "if we remove the word yoga...". Why are we discussing removing words?

Comment: No no, here, `yoga = body+mind+spirit`, it is union of these 3. If we remove `mind+spirit` then `yoga = body` . So, this will not be yoga this will be something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83594/discussion-between-alec-and-user10321971).